# Do I have to refresh the oauth2 access_token myself, or

Tags: python, google-app-engine, oauth, oauth-2.0

I use the Google APIs Client Library for Python (oauth2client app engine). When the access_token expires, do I have to refresh it myself or will it be done by the API?
Now the access_token expires and is not refreshed!

I use the oauth aware decorator. The access type = offline and the refresh token is inside the credentials.

This is the TokenInfo I have received:

```
{
 "issued_to": "1002825648120.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "audience": "1002825648120.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "user_id": "110738386197429542823",
 "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
 "expires_in": 3540,
 "email": "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
 "verified_email": true,
 "access_type": "offline"
}
```

If I have to refresh the access_token, is there an easy method in the oauth client API to do that?

**UPDATE-1 :**

I studied the code of oauth2/client.py. I now think that failing to use decorator.http() results in not refreshing the access token. See this (my other) question:
[Failed to authorize tokeninfo oauth2 request using decorator.http()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12915253/failed-to-authorize-tokeninfo-oauth2-request-using-decorator-http)

**UPDATE-2 : SOLVED :**

The problem mentioned above (in UPDATE-1) was solved and also solved this question. The API will try to refresh the access_token (if expired) when calling an authorized http.request.

Comment: True. The API suppose to refresh your token after its expiration. This is done using the refresh-token if available, or by asking the user to enter credentials again (if not available in the session/cookie)

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I studied the code of oauth2/client.py. I now think that failing to use decorator.http() results in not refreshing the access token. See this (my other) question: Failed to authorize tokeninfo oauth2 request using decorator.http()

UPDATE and SOLVED :

The problem mentioned above was solved and also solved this question. The API will try to refresh the access_token (if expired) when calling an authorized http.request.